# Why don't medications related to suicide warn against pregnancy?

Tags: discussion

I've edited [Why don't medications related to suicide warn against pregnancy?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18721/14407), but please inform me if I can clarify anything else?

Answer (score 3):

Your edit does clarify your question but your reasoning is such a stretch of logic that I'm going to let the community decide on reopening the question. It will require five votes to reopen, or one of the other mods.

Comment: 1. 'your reasoning is such a stretch of logic': How? 2. Anyhow, I don't think 'your reasoning is such a stretch of logic' is a close reason?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal 1) Explain why every drug that might have an impact on people with suicidal ideations should carry an anti-pregnancy warning, 2) it's not closed.

Comment: My question is closed, yes? "closed as unclear what you're asking"

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal I don't know what question you're referring to. I don't see any questions from you on this or the Medical Sciences forum.